# Building iteration function of vector's vector in template class

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I am currently programming a template matrix.
the matrix have a

```
vector<vector<T>> names mat, and contains the vectors size (rows and cols).
```

How to i build a const function that iterates over a vector of vectors?

Notice: I need to build a

```
typedef typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator const_iterator
```

i am asking how to build the iterator function and not how to use an iterator.

so far that's all i have:

```
typedef typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator const_iterator;

const_iterator end()
{
    return mat[rowsNum][colsNum];
}

const_iterator begin()
{
    return mat[0][0];
}
```

which had a previous try:
    typedef typename std::vector::const_iterator const_iterator;

```
const_iterator end()
{
    return mat.end;
}

const_iterator begin()
{
    return mat.begin;
}
```

-- EDIT --
at the moment, my code looks like that:

```
template<class T>
class Matrix
{
private:
...
public:
...
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    const_iterator end()
    {
        return mat[rowsNum][colsNum];
    }

    const_iterator begin()
    {
        return mat[0][0];
    }
}
}
```

and that's it.
is it a problem?

Comment: Yuck. Yet another implementation of a jagged-edged "matrix" with memory being allocated all over the place. Every time I see one of these things I die a little inside.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid using `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`. It is not contiguous in memory, not efficient, treating iterators from that is not straightforward.

I would suggest you since you seem to want to use a Matrix container is to flatten your array and use a linear `std::vector<T>` instead so that you just have to reuse `std::vector<T>::const_iterator`.

**Example**

```
 template<class T>
 struct Matrix {
    using const_iterator = std::vector<T>::const_iterator;
    std::vector<T> mat;
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;

    // [...] constructors etc...

    const_iterator end() const {
        return mat.end();
    }

    const_iterator begin() const {
        return mat.begin();
    }
    // and you don't need to specify anything else for your iterators.

    const T& operator()(size_t i, size_t j) const { return mat[i * rows + j]; } // depends if row major or column major storage
    // [...] and other convenient methods...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have vector of vectors, so, your iterator should be

```
typedef typename std::vector<std::vector<T>>::const_iterator const_iterator;
```

And functions should be

```
const_iterator end() const
{
    return mat.end();
}

const_iterator begin() const
{
    return mat.begin();
}
```

Comment: could not convert '((const Matrix<int>*)this)->Matrix<int>::mat.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >()' from 'std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*, std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >}'

Comment: to 'Matrix<int>::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >}'
         return mat.begin();

Comment: @COOKIE you use right typedef, from my post, yeah? It so, should be fine.

Comment: exepct for this: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<char>' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'

Comment: @COOKIE it's another question and another problem. You have no operator << in code, that you post.

Comment: i actually do have this operator, but i think it only operates on whole matrixes and not on parts-of-matrix

Comment: friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Matrix<T>& m)